# Flutter - Right overflowed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

When I put a Text widget just for test, the program shows "A RenderFlex overflowed by 34 pixels on the right.". I tried to put the Text in a Container, but it isn't works too. Look the print:

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: CupertinoTextField(
                prefix: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    IconData(0xF4A4,
                        fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons",
                        fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage),
                    color: CupertinoColors.darkBackgroundGray,
                  ),
                ),
                placeholder: 'O que você procura?',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0),
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                child: Icon(
                    IconData(0xF370,
                        fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons",
                        fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage),
                    size: 80.0,
                    color: CupertinoColors.black),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGroupedBackground,
    ),
    child: Text("Teste"),
  );
```

[image: look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiled allright for me. But consider placing the text in a `Column` or `Expanded` widget, something will try to take all the space available. (`Text` widgets only become as big as they need to be, maybe something goes wrong popping that directly into the `CupertinoPageScaffold`)